# POST /post/29/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Tags: python, django

Хочу добавить комментарии к посту в моем блоге на Django, но когда я жму отправить, то появляется эта ошибка `POST /post/29/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0`

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType




class Post(models.Model):
    published = None
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()
    header_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images/")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Some String")
    body = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    #date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['name', 'body']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import CommentForm
from .models import Post


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    #paginate_by = 2
    #model = Contact

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'header_image']

class BlogDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

@property
def image_url(self):
    """
    Return self.photo.url if self.photo is not None,
    'url' exist and has a value, else, return None.
    """
    if self.image:
        return getattr(self.photo, 'url', None)
    return None

def detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.post = post
            obj.save()

            return redirect('detail', slug=post.slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'post_delete.html', context)
```

**myblog/urls.py**

```
    from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    BlogListView,
    BlogDetailView,
    BlogCreateView,
    BlogUpdateView,
    BlogDeleteView,
    comment_detail
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', BlogDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('post/<int:slug>/comments', comment_detail, name='comments'),
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),

]
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('', include('myblog.urls')),
    path('comment/', include('comment.urls')),
    path('api/', include('comment.api.urls'))

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post-entry">
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ post.body|urlize }}</p>
    </div>

    <p><a href="{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}">+ Edit Blog Post</a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'post_delete' post.pk %}">+ Delete Blog Post</a></p>
    {% if post.header_image %}
        <p><img src="{{post.header_image.url}}"></p>
    {% else %}
        <p></p>
    {% endif %}


    {% for comm in post.commentpost_set.all%}
        {{ comm.user }} <br>
        {{ comm.text }} <br><br>
    {% endfor %}

    <article class="content" >

        <br><hr>
        <h2>Add a comment</h2>

        <form method="post" action='{% url 'comments' %}'>
            {% csrf_token %}


            {{ form.as_table }}
            <p>Name: </p>
            <input name="Name" type="text">
            <p>Body: </p><textarea></textarea><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </article>

{% endblock content %}
```

Я не так давно начал изучать Django, поэтому извините за бардак в коде.
Буду благодарен даже за маленький совет, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Возможно у формы, где создаются комментарии нету action. Укажите action. Туда вы должны поместить имя url-a, к которому присвоена view для создания комментов.

Примерно так:

`path('articles/<int:id>/comments',comment_create,name='comments')`

```
def comment_create(request):
    #сама логика                                                               
    return render(request,'template.html')
```

И в шаблоне template.html:

```
<form method="POST" action='{% url 'comments' %}'>
...
</form>
```

Или же вы не указали метод у формы. Ну в данном случае у вас создание комментов и нужно поставить method="POST" в теге form

Comment: в **urls.py** добавил вот эту строчку
`path('post/<int:id>/comments', comment_detail(), name='comments'),`
в шаблоне **post_detail.html** сделал также как у вас, после этих изменений почему то появился такая ошибка 
`TypeError: comment_detail() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'request' and 'slug'
`

Comment: Не обязательно добавлять ту строчку, которую я написал(это же был просто пример). А эта ошибка значит, что функция comment_detail имеет 2 обязательных аргумента  request и slug, соответственно передайте эти аргументы в функцию

Comment: я уже с другой ошибкой разбираюсь

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'comments' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<slug>[0-9]+)/comments$']
`

Comment: NoReverseMatch - скорее всего тут вы не передали аргументы при построении ссылки в шаблоне или указали их неправильно

Comment: Я сейчас отредактирую оба **urls.py** файла, чекни пж

Comment: path('post/<int:slug>/comments', comment_detail, name='comments') . Вопрос, как slug может быть integer, если это slug? :) Для него обычно указывают тип str или у вас slug это число?

Comment: Можете мне рассказать, что у вас сейчас за проблема? Точно такая-же?

Comment: у меня ошибка
`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'comments' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<slug>[0-9]+)/comments$']`
slug я не помню уже из-за чего написал или по гайду, или на этом сайте посоветовали, не помню

Comment: Покажите шаблон, где происходит данная ошибка(ну то есть шаблон той страницы, при переходе на которую у вас возникает данная ошибка)

Comment: Форму комментария не углядел. При добавлении комментария форма отправляет пост запрос на страницу поста, из-за чего ошибка. А это происходит тк `action` формы не указан. Автор ответа прав

Comment: @Миша, короче говоря, когда я жму на пост, у меня появляется эта ошибка, это если я не ошибаюсь **post_detail.html**, а его я показал здесь

Comment: @ZaArs, я изменил action, можете посмотреть, но это ничего не меняет

Comment: в вашем вопросе не указан пример вашего `comment_detail`